# MapReduce values in reducer always size 1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am using Cloudera to implement a mapreduce job. My input is a json and looks like this:

```
{"reviewerID": "A2PUSR7ROG0Z6T", "asin": "9742356831", "reviewerName": "Terry Bisgrove \"Mr.E.Man\"", "helpful": [2, 2], "reviewText": "I like other styles of Mae Ploy curry paste, but the green just doesn't work for me. Overwhelming garlic, no heat, and very bland. I would not purchase this product again.", "overall": 3.0, "summary": "OK Product", "unixReviewTime": 1344297600, "reviewTime": "08 7, 2012"}
{"reviewerID": "A2ANBEX40KLY4O", "asin": "9742356831", "reviewerName": "TrishS \"TrishS\"", "helpful": [3, 4], "reviewText": "I have both the red and green curry paste.  The green is milder.  I use both of them in variety of dishes and often spice up soups and stews that need a little zing.  It is so convient to have them in the frig.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Tasty and fast", "unixReviewTime": 1310601600, "reviewTime": "07 14, 2011"}
{"reviewerID": "A1C8NAHYR6Z10F", "asin": "B00004S1C5", "reviewerName": "A. Horikawa", "helpful": [1, 2], "reviewText": "These dyes create awesome colors for kids crafts. I have used them to make finger paint, paint, play dough, and salt dough.Another reviewer stated that they are not natural - this is CORRECT. They are definitely artificial dyes. I tried making my own dyes, and when that fell through, these worked great in a pinch. You only need a couple drops for really vibrant color. And they are pretty easy to clean - don't stain after they've been made into whatever craft.Good product for the price!", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Great for kids crafts!", "unixReviewTime": 1344297600, "reviewTime": "08 7, 2012"}
{"reviewerID": "A14YSMLYLJEMET", "asin": "B00004S1C5", "reviewerName": "Amazon Customer", "helpful": [8, 11], "reviewText": "This product is no where near natural / organic-I only wish I had seen the other reviews before purchasing! It contains all the things I did not want-which is why I was looking for a natural alternative. They need to have an ingredient list on here to avoid this...I am &#34;returning&#34; item. I am trying to avoid my children's exposure to yellow 5, red 40 and so on...I do not understand how they can still make these things knowing what they can cause. This may be fine for someone that doesn't read labels or care what their kids eat-but not for my family.", "overall": 1.0, "summary": "Not natural/organic at all", "unixReviewTime": 1364515200, "reviewTime": "03 29, 2013"}
...
```

My mapper selects the values from "asin" and "reviewText" of this json:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SentimentMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(value.toString());
      context.write(new Text(obj.getString("asin")), new Text(obj.getString("reviewText")));

  }

}
```

And finally, my reducer goes through all values and writes the size of the value list for each key:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class SentimentReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(Text val : values) {
          list.add(new String(val.toString()));
      }

      context.write(key, new Text(String.valueOf(list.size())));

  }
}
```

Unfortunately I end up with this result:

```
616719923X  1
9742356831  1
B00004S1C5  1
B0000531B7  1
B00005344V  1
B0000537AF  1
B00005C2M2  1
B00006IUTN  1
B0000CCZYY  1
B0000CD06J  1
B0000CDBQN  1
B0000CDEPD  1
B0000CETGM  1
B0000CFLCT  1
B0000CFLIL  1
```

Which means that the sizes for all keys are always 1. As you can see in my input json, for some keys (e.g. B00004S1C5), there should be multiple values. Can anyone help me on this issue please?

Update: Here is the driver class as requested:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

public class SentimentDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    /*
     * Validate that two arguments were passed from the command line.
     */
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.printf("Usage: StubDriver <input dir> <output dir>\n");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    /*
     * Instantiate a Job object for your job's configuration. 
     */
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "job_13");

    /*
     * Specify an easily-decipherable name for the job.
     * This job name will appear in reports and logs.
     */
    job.setJobName("job_13");

    job.setJarByClass(SentimentDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(SentimentMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(SentimentReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SentimentReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    /*
     * Start the MapReduce job and wait for it to finish.
     * If it finishes successfully, return 0. If not, return 1.
     */
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but I export it as a runnable JAR file and call it from the command line.

Comment: Post the full Mapper and Reducer Class.

Comment: post the driver class details....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update:**
you don't need combiner in your program, please remove or comment combiner in driver class and that should fix your program!....

combiner sends input to reducer:

```
9742356831 ----- 2
B00004S1C5 ----- 2
```

hence reducer outputs:

```
9742356831 ----- 1
B00004S1C5 ----- 1
```

I tested your code **with out combiner** and gave me expected results, but I would re-write your program as:

---

**output:**

```
9742356831  2
B00004S1C5  2
```

---

```
public static class jsonDataMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            JSONObject obj;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(value.toString());
                //context.write(new Text(obj.getString("asin")), new Text(obj.getString("reviewText")));
                context.write(new Text(obj.getString("asin")), new IntWritable(1));
            } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      
          }
    }

    public  static class jsonDataReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {

         public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
//                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//                for(Text val : values) {
//                    list.add(new String(val.toString()));
//                }
//
//                context.write(key, new Text(String.valueOf(list.size())));

             int sum=0;
             for(IntWritable i: values)
                  sum+=i.get();
             context.write(key, new Text(String.valueOf(sum)));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your refactored program works for me as well, however as I need to do some string comparisons in the reducer I would hope to get my original program working.

Comment: removing/commenting combiner config will fix your code!

Comment: Awesome, its working! Thank you very much, I would never have guessed that the bug was in the driver.